# While loop fails to exit when a false condition is passed to it

Tags: c++, while-loop

Consider the following code to calculate the sum of numbers which are inputted by user during runtime :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;         //stores sum of numbers
    int taken;           //stores the number inputted by the user
    while(cin>>taken)    
    {
         sum += taken;
    }

    cout<<"The sum is : "<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I expect the loop to exit on its own and display the sum of numbers inputted by user as soon as the user enters 0 because `while(0)` evaluates to false as a result of which the loop terminates and hence the statement printing sum of numbers should be executed.

But this does not occur.

So, why does the `while` loop does not exit when the user enters 0 as an input ?

---

### Please consider my below sample run of program :

- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0
- 5

(Then finally pressing ctrl-z for indicating end-of-file)

The sum is : 11

---

### Here is my doubt in above sample run :

After I had entered 0, I should not be prompted for further inputs because according to me, `while(0)` should evaluate to false, and therefore the statement telling the sum of numbers entered till 0 should be printed on the screen, which does not happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `cin>>taken` is not the value of `taken`. That's your misunderstanding.

You could write this code

```
while (cin >> taken && taken != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

which would do what you want.

As a side note the value of `cin >> taken` reflects the *stream state*. Normally in a boolean context a stream evaluates to true, but if some kind of error has occured then the stream evaluates to false. This is why `while (cin >> taken)` effectively means read until no more integers can be read.

Answer (score 2):

> So, why does the `while` loop does not exit when the user enters 0 as an input ?

`while (cin >> taken)` doesn't evaluate to `while (taken)` but to `while (bool(cin))`. After reading into the variable, `cin` will be casted to `bool`, which checks if the stream has errors.

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> #### Return value
>
> `true` if the stream has no errors, `false` otherwise.